# Problema de CORS intentando hacer solicitudes a un backend con framework Apache Causeway

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, cors

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion para la universidad, y nos obligan a usar el framework de desarrollo de aplicaciones DDD Apache Causeway (que tiene una documentacion muy pobre)
Causeway (Isis anteriormente) te crea una API RESTful, a partir de las entidades de dominio que se definen. Pero al intentar enviar una request desde un frontend, navegador, larga error de CORS, ya busque en la documentacion y en este framework los CORS ya vienen habilitados por defecto, es decir, el origen, las peticiones, etc. De igual forma busque e intente modificar la configuracion de CORS, pero nada funciono, desde crear una clase de configuracion, hasta agregar las anotaciones en las clases de propiedades.

Esto es lo que la API espera del metodo LoginJugador:

[image: Esto es lo que espera el metodo LoginJugador de la API:]

Este es el codigo que utilizo para usar el metodo:

```
  const password = "1234";

  const raw = JSON.stringify({
    telefono: {
      value: telefono,
    },
    password: {
      value: password,
    },
  });

  var requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { Authorization: "Basic c3ZlbjpwYXNz"},
    body: raw,
    
    
  };

  fetch(
    "http://localhost:8080/restful/services/simple.LoginJugador/actions/LoginJugador/invoke",
    requestOptions
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const valorBooleano = data.result.value;
      console.log(valorBooleano);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("error", error);
    });
```

Y este es el error que me devuelve la consola de cualquier navegador:

'http://localhost:8080/restful/services/simple.LoginJugador/actions/LoginJugador/invoke' from origin 'chrome://startpage' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.